# ERROR: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied Warning: You are no longer connected to ORACLE

Tags: oracle, database-administration, oracle12c

I am using Oracle 12C.
These are the steps I followed

```
1] SQLPLUS SYS/<password> as SYSDBA;
2] show con_name; //CDB$ROOT;
3] Created a new PDB;
4] ALTER SESSSION SET CONTAINER = PDB5;
5] show con_name; //pdb5
6] show user; //sys
7] CREATE USER karan IDENTIFIED BY shah CONTAINER = CURRENT;
8] GRANT CONNECT, RESOURCE TO karan;
9] CONNECT karan/shah;
```

gives error

```
ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied


Warning: You are no longer connected to ORACLE.
```

What I am doing wrong ? I understand I am creating a local user specific to the PDB. Also what is the query to see all the local users of PDB, common users of CDB? Thank

Answer (score 0):

The container name seems to be missing in the conn string

```
CONNECT karan/shah@PDB5
```